# Почему здесь причастный оборот обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот, уточнения

Почему причастный оборот «переходной ко всему лучшему» обособляется в следующем предложении?

> Ей, может быть, захотелось заявить женскую самостоятельность, пойти
> против общественных условий, против деспотизма своего родства и
> семейства, а услужливая фантазия убедила ее, положим, на один только
> миг, что Федор Павлович, несмотря на свой чин приживальщика, все-таки
> один из смелейших и насмешливейших людей той, переходной ко всему
> лучшему, эпохи, тогда как он был только злой шут и больше ничего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, ответ можно найти в разделе "[**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_22.htm)" (Розенталь):

> Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений ***этот, тот, такой, каждый, один*** (в значении местоимения) и т. п.: *Хотелось отличиться перед этим, **дорогим для меня,** человеком* (М. Г.); *Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего этого, **так нашумевшего,** дерзновения* (А. Т.)... *Между ними давно уже установились те, **чисто формальные,** отношения, которые так обычны между двумя родственниками* (М. Г.)...

В рассматриваемом предложении из "Братьев Карамазовых" общее значение местоимения ***той*** (одной из эпох) уточняется, то есть виден переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому. А в отличие от пояснительных определений, уточняющие выделяются с обеих сторон.

По поводу "причастного оборота". Слово ***переходной*** является прилагательным, а весь оборот – обособленным согласованным определением. Даже если кто-то не согласится с этим, можно в этом же разделе Розенталя прочитать:

> **Примечания:** 1. Писатели-классики иногда выделяли запятыми в качестве уточняющего определения **причастный оборот**, стоящий поcле однородного определения-прилагательного. Например, у И. С. Тургенева: *Он устроил большую, **полотном покрытую,** купальню; В ста шагах от мельницы находился маленький, **со всех сторон открытый,** навес; Из особенной,  **мною сперва не замеченной,** конюшни вывели Павлина.* В настоящее время такая пунктуация встречается редко.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, желаю вам дальнейших успехов.

Comment: @Sharon Данке шён!

Answer (score 1):

Обособляется, потому что без запятых "*та переходная ко всему лучшему эпоха*" означает, что таких эпох **несколько**, а говорится именно о той (ранее обозначенной). Тогда это неоднородные определения. Например:
*Хочу ту дорогую машину, у которой зелёный цвет.*

В случае с запятыми имеет место уточнение:
*той, [а именно] переходной ко всему лучшему, эпохи*

С местоимениями существует ещё и третий вариант пунктуации:
*Машина должна быть быстрой. Хочу такую [быструю], зелёную машину.* || Такую и зелёную. Однородные определения. Этот вариант менее всех характерен для русского языка.